# Ubuntu 18.04.1 TouchPad Issues

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I have a Mediacom Flex with Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed. But the touchpad and the monitor touch does not work.
Here there is the response  of `xinput list`

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 PC Camera: PC Camera              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The strange thing is that they seem to be not present.
PS: in Ubuntu Live CD the monitor touch does work.

Can you help me?